# Change url asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, maproute

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyRoute",
            url: "{Product}/{name}-{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Product", name = UrlParameter.Optional , id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

my routemap and i want my url in product action be like = http://localhost:13804/Wares/Product/name-id

but now is like = 
http://localhost:13804/Wares/Product/4?name=name

Comment: What is `{Product}` for ? Is it a parameter of your action method ? How does your action method looks like ? and what is `Wares` in your url ? should that be mapped to the product param ?

Comment: Product is action for show my products in it
Wares in my controller

Comment: What is `Ware` in your url ?

Comment: i said {ware} is my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a route pattern the token `{` and `}` are used to indicate a parameter of the action method. Since you do not have a parameter called Product in your action method, there is no point in having `{Product}` in the route template.

Since your want url like `yourSiteName/Ware/Product/name-id` where `name` and `id` are dynamic parameter values, you should add the static part (`/Ware/Product/`) to the route template.

This should work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyRoute",
    url: "Ware/Product/{name}-{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Ware", action = "Product", 
                  name = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Assuming your Product action method accepts these two params

```
public class WareController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Product(string name, int id)
    {
        return Content("received name : " + name +",id:"+ id);
    }
}
```

You can generate the urls with the above pattern using the Html.ActionLink helper now

```
@Html.ActionLink("test", "Product", "Ware", new { id = 55, name = "some" }, null)
```

Comment: `code    public ActionResult Product(int? id)

        {

            if (id == null)

            {

                return new 
HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            }

            Ware ware = db.Wares.Find(id);

            if (ware == null)

            {

                return HttpNotFound();

            }

            return View(ware);

        }    `

this is my action in wares controller and and ur answer not worked for me

Comment: what you mean it is not working ? what specifically is not working ? and why don't you have a name param in your action ?

Comment: i do what u say and again in url i have http://localhost:13804/Wares/Product/4?name=name

Comment: How are you generating the link ? Are you doing what i mentioned in the answer (last part) ?

Comment: Then it should work. I just tested in a local project.Make sure you are using the overload which has 5 params.

Comment: It,s Work
i did int? and mistake was here
ty so much

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but you can use built-in Attribute Routing in MVC5. Hope it helps someone else. You **don't need** to use

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyRoute",
            url: "{Product}/{name}-{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Product", name = UrlParameter.Optional , id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Instead you can use the method below.
First enable attribute routing in **RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Then in WaresController

```
[Route("Wares/Product/{name}/{id}")]
public ActionResult Product(string name,int id)
{
   return View();
}
```

Then to navigate write code like this in View.cshtml file

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Product","Wares",new { name="productname",id="5"})">Navigate</a>
```

After following above steps your URL will look like
**http://localhost:13804/Wares/Product/productname/5**